# What exactly do these integral functions mean?

Tags: calculus

$$F(x) = \int{f(x)}\,dx$$

$$G(x) = \int_0^x{g(z)}\,dz$$

I am confused about the exact meaning about these functions.  The second function is clear to me, $G(x)$ is just the area under the graph of $g(x)$ from $0$ to some $x$.  But the first function is not so clear.

Also, why is the following considered incorrect?

$$H(x) = \int_0^x{g(x)}\,dx$$

Comment: Well the first formula would only define $F$ up to an additive constant. The third is considered poor notation as the 'dummy variable' appears also as a limit. That is, the $x$ inside the integral is a formal notation indicating 'what' is being integrated. The $x$ in the limit is some fixed number. The two are unrelated, so shouldn't be denoted by the same letter.

Comment: Isn't $F(x)$ just the function obtained from doing the integral of $f(x)$?

For example you have $F(x) = \int \frac {1}{x}dx$ and when you do the integration you'd get $\log (x) + C$ so $F(x) = \log (x) + C$.

Comment: $F(x)+C=\int f(x) dx \text{ where } F'=f$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are good questions.

The notation $\displaystyle \int f(x) dx$ is shorthand for "an antiderivative of $f(x)$." That is, a function with the property that $F'(x) = f(x)$. Part of the depth of the fundamental theorem of calculus is that antiderivatives are also ways to calculate the area under a curve. This is remarkable - why should they be related?

The last piece you wrote, $H(x) = \displaystyle \int_0^x g(x) dx$ is terrible notation, and should not be written in front of a non-expert crowd (experts can take in notational abuse much easier than neophytes). It it far more correct to write
$$
H(x) = \int_0^x g(t) dt
$$
to not confuse dummy variables and the actual variable.

Answer (score 0):

$$
H(x) = \int_0^x{g(x)}\,dx
$$
is not incorrect (just confusing for unexperienced students).  This function $H$ is an antiderivative of $g$; that is $H'=g$.  But usually we write $G'=g$ and $F'=f$ since it is easier to remember what is what.

Formula
$$
F(x) = \int{f(x)}\,dx
$$
is known as an *indefinite integral* and means $F'=f$.

Comment: Arguably it is incorrect: naming bound and unbound variables with the same letter in formulae is both confusing and ambiguous: consider the case $ \int_0^x f(x,y) \, dy $.